# Is there a way to fetch dynamic distribution lists via graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Office 365 groups (distribution lists) listed at `/groups` api endpoint just fine, but it seems dynamic distribution lists created at exchange admin portal excluded from that api endpoint. 
Is there any api to fetch all dynamic distribution lists of particular tenant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distribution groups are only exposed in Exchange PowerShell today, and are not currently supported via the Microsoft Graph API.

Please vote on this feature request on UserVoice: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38178205-list-members-from-exchange-dynamic-distribution-gr